# Image/text recognition for android

Tags: android

An application I want to implement must use camera to recognize a complex entity consisting of an image and some text. Depending on the text different scenarios must be triggered.

What are my options ? openCV ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android NDK and OpenCV

It's available here
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

The android package contains prebuilt opencv's libraries, so you dont have to build it from source which is very nice. Also, they have lots of examples of how to use opencv camera or android camera to do color/image recognition.

Comment: The problem is that you need to install a separate application in order to have OCR feature